# $\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+3}}{n}\right)$ Converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+3}}{n}\right)$

I want to prove that the sequence converges or diverges. The limit is $0$. Thus, $l = 0$. $ | a_n - l| = \left(\frac{\left|(-1\right)^{n+3}|}{|n|}\right)$  at this point, if I say $\le \left(\frac{\left(1\right)}{n}\right)$ therefore $N = 1/\epsilon$ is it correct?

Comment: Why does everyone want to prove convergence using epsilon-delta? $\dfrac{-1}n \le a_n \le \dfrac1n$ is much simpler and much more elegant.

Comment: @DHMO perhaps just practicing the definition with "simple" examples for fun, learning, an upcoming exam, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an epsilon delta proof:

Notice:

$$-1 \leq (-1)^{n+3} \leq 1$$

Hence:

$$\frac{-1}{n} \leq \frac{(-1)^{n+3}}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

And by squeeze theorem it follows that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+3}}{n} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$u_{2n}=\frac{-1}{2n}\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}u_{2n}=0$$

and

$$u_{2n+1}=\frac {1}{2n+1}\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}u_{2n+1}=0$$

both subsequences have the same limit, so the sequence $(u_n) $ goes to $0$.